# Execution Timed Out (Задача на CodeWars)

Tags: c#

Выполняю задачу на CodeWars:
Ребенок играет с мячом на n-м этаже высотного здания. Высота этого этажа h известна.

Он бросает мяч из окна. Мяч отскакивает (например) на две трети своей высоты (отскок 0,66).

Его мать смотрит из окна в 1,5 метрах от земли.

Сколько раз мать увидит, как мяч проходит перед ее окном (в том числе когда он падает и подпрыгивает?

Для достоверности эксперимента должны быть соблюдены три условия:
Плавающий параметр "h" в метрах должен быть больше 0
Плавающий параметр "bounce" должен быть больше 0 и меньше 1
Плавающий параметр "окно" должен быть меньше h.
Если все три условия выше выполнены, вернуть положительное целое число, иначе вернуть -1.

В IDE код работает без ошибок, как надо, и при тесте на CodeWars получаю положительный результат, но при финальной попытке запуска кода я получаю: Execution Timed Out (12000 ms)
Даже предположить не могу, с чем это связано...
Помогите, пожалуйста:3

```
    public static int bouncingBall(double h, double bounce, double window)
    {
        if (h<0||window>h ||bounce < 0 || bounce > 1)
            return -1;
        int result = 0;
        while (h>window)
        {
            result += (h > window) ? 1 : 0;
            h = h * bounce;
            result += (h > window) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return result;
        
    }
```

Comment: добавь перевод задачи

Comment: какие ограничения на h? Ошибка может говорить о том, что введено слишком большое значение и цикл просто не успевает закончиться

Comment: на самом деле цикл вообще не нужен. Рассмотри изменение `h` как геометрическую прогрессию, по сути достаточно определить номер члена геометрической прогрессии, который меньше `window`.

Comment: @Grundy спасибо за подсказку про прогрессию, но я не понимаю, как можно это реализовать без цикла или без рекурсии, или как раз рекурсией и надо искать?

Comment: добавь пример входных выходных данных, чтобы можно было проверить

Comment: @Grundy ну вот прям из задачи пример: h = 3, bounce = 0.66, window = 1.5, результат = 3, как и предполагалось. Да я и увеличивать пытался значения переменных, например, h = 100, алгоритм выполняется быстро, да и я сомневаюсь, что в условия задачи добавили бы безмерные значения переменных...

Comment: если ограничений нет - подставить могут любое число из диапазона значений `double`

Comment: добавь ссылку на саму задачу

Comment: странно, твое решение в принципе совпадает с принятыми, не должно было быть проблем

Answer (score 2):

Приведенный пример кода соответствует принятым решениям. Неизвестно, почему появляется ошибка при проверке.

В любом случае, для решения данной задачи можно вообще отказаться от цикла.

Рассмотрим высоты, на которые поднимается отскакивающий мяч.

Они образуют собой геометрическую прогрессию, в которой первый член равен `h`, и знаменателем прогрессии является `bounce`.

Таким образом, задачу можно свести к нахождению номера члена прогрессии, который будет меньше заданного числа.

`n-ый` член прогрессии может быть вычислен по формуле:

```
bn = b0 * qn
```

номер члена можно найти следующим образом:

```
n = logq(bn / b0);
```

Из-за того, что b<sub>n</sub> не задан, а задано число, большее его в результате получим дробный `n` между последним видимым и первым невидимым.

Округляем в большую сторону до целого и получаем искомое значение.

Каждому номеру, кроме первого, соответствует два момента, когда мяч виден, таким образом конечное решение будет

```
n*2 - 1
```